# Why does this integral vanish? $\int_C \frac{e^{az}}{1+e^z}dz$

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm looking for an argument that would prove that the integral

$$I=\int_C \frac{e^{az}}{1+e^z}dz$$

vanishes for $R \to \infty$, where $C$ is the horizontal line segment from $(1+i)R$ to $(-1+i)R$, and $a \in (0,1)$. Here $R$ goes to infinity 'discretely', so as to avoid the singularies at $(2n+1)\pi i$, the line segment is placed between the subsequent singularities. Parametrizing the contour with $z(t)=iR+t, \ t\in[-R,R]$ and attempting to bound the integral gives me:

$$|I| \le \int_{-R}^{R} \frac{e^{at}dt}{|1+e^{t+iR}|}$$

but I don't know what to do with this, using the reverse tringle inequality doesn't help because the denominator becomes $e^t -1$, and the integral goes through zero...

Additional information:

This problem cropped up when doing the following exercise: "By choosing a suitable contour, show that  $$\int_\mathbb{R} \frac{e^{ax}}{1+e^x}dx = \frac{\pi}{\sin(a\pi)},$$ where $0<a<1$. I managed to solve this integral now, by choosing the integration contour to be a rectangle with vertices $\pm R, \pm R + 2\pi i$. But originally, I was trying the verteces $\pm R, (\pm 1+i)R$, where the values of $R$ are restricted so the contour doesn't go through a singularity. Letting $R$ to infinity will then have the contour capture all of the residues on the positive imaginary axis, the sum of which (times $2 \pi i$) is precisely $\frac{\pi}{\sin(a\pi)}$, meaning the top part has to tend to zero. Letting $R$ change in discrete steps, $R_n = 2\pi n$ gives a nonzero value of the top integral though, namely $$I_{top} = e^{2\pi i a n} I_n$$ where $$I_n = \int_{-2\pi n}^{2 \pi n} f(x)dx.$$ So, in the limit, things don't actually work out because of the weird oscillatory term. But apparently, taking the limit is not even necessary, as the top integral is always proportional to the bottom one, so their sum is equal to the residues contained inside, which are calculated easily enough.

Comment: Roughly speaking, since $|e^{iR}|=1$, the denominator behaves like $e^t$ for $t \gg 1$. Hence the whole function behaves like $e^{(a-1)t}$, and now you should recall that $0<a<1$.

Comment: I'm looking to translate this 'rough speaking' into an actual set of inequalities that would lead to the desired conclusion :)

Comment: I'm not sure about the soundness of that going to infinity "discretely": making $\;R\to\infty\;$ on the straight line $\;y=iR\;$ will make the path cross infinite poles (in fact, **all** of them) and this cannot be healthy...

Comment: Well, I'm not sure about it either, but in the problem I'm trying to solve everything works out if I can make that integral vanish. Why can't I consider discrete $R_n$'s, each located between the poles? The sum of the residues at the poles gives $\frac{\pi}{\sin{a \pi}}$, and I have to show this to be equal to the integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{ax}dx}{1+e^x}$. Choosing a rectangle with verteces at $\pm R, (\pm 1 +i)R$ and letting $R$ go to infinity produces this result, provided that the 'top' part vanishes (the sides I've already shown to vanish).

Comment: I don't think you can consider discrete $\;R\;$ as you're working all along with continuous variables. What you can do is to take a little semicircle around a general (around **any** ) pole $\;\eta_n=(2n+1)\pi\;$ , say $\;\{z\in\Bbb C\;;\;|z-\eta_n|=\epsilon\in\Bbb R\}\;$ and prove the integral on that semicircle vanishes when $\;\epsilon\to 0\;$

Comment: Obviously you CAN consider R to be a sequence of discrete values.  For example, consider $\lim_{n\to\infty} F(R_n)$, where $F(R)$ is the integral you are interested in, and $R_n$ is any sequence that converges to infinity and so that $e^{i R_n} = 1$, e.g. $R_n = 2\pi n$.

Comment: I'm getting mixed messages here.

Comment: So your real problem is calculating $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{e^{ax}}{1+e^x}\ \mathrm{d}x$ with $a\in(0,1)$ using the residue theorem, right? Was the contour given or is it yours?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, the integral $I$ does **not** converge to $0$ as $R \to \infty$:

For $R \notin \{(2k+1) \cdot \pi; k \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ let $$I(R) := \int_C \frac{e^{a \cdot z}}{1+e^{z}} \, dz$$ where the contour $C$ is parametrized by $z(t) = \imath \, R +t$, $t \in [-R,R]$. By definition, we have

$$\begin{align*} I(R) &= \imath \, e^{\imath \, a \cdot R} \cdot \int_{-R}^R \frac{e^{a \cdot t}}{1+e^{\imath \, R+t}}  \, dt \\ &=\imath \, e^{\imath \, a \cdot R} \cdot \int_{-R}^R \frac{e^{a \cdot t}}{1+e^{\imath \, R+t}} \cdot \frac{1+e^{-\imath \, R + t}}{1+e^{-\imath \, R+t}} \, dt \\
&= \imath \, e^{\imath \, a \cdot R} \cdot \int_{-R}^R \frac{e^{a \cdot t}+e^{(a+1) \cdot t} \cdot e^{-\imath \, R}}{e^{2t}+\cos^2(R)+2e^t \cdot \cos^2(R)} \, dt \\
&= \imath \, e^{\imath \, a \cdot R} \cdot (I_1(R)-\imath \, I_2(R)) \end{align*}$$

where

$$\begin{align*} I_1(R) &:= \int_{-R}^R \frac{e^{a \cdot t}+e^{(a+1) \cdot t} \cdot \cos(R)}{e^{2t}+\cos^2(R)+2e^t \cdot \cos^2(R)} \, dt \\ I_2(R) &:= \sin(R) \cdot \int_{-R}^R \frac{e^{(a+1) \cdot t}}{e^{2t}+\cos^2(R)+2e^t \cdot \cos^2(R)} \, dt \end{align*}$$

Now pick a sequence $(R_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $R_n \to \infty$ and $R_n \notin \{(2k+1) \cdot \pi; k \in \mathbb{N}\}$ for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$. The calculation above shows that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} I(R_n) = 0 \Leftrightarrow \lim_{n \to \infty}  I_1(R_n) = \lim_{n \to \infty} I_2(R_n) = 0$$ First of all, by the positivity of the integrand,

$$\begin{align*} |I_2(R_n)| &\geq |\sin(R_n)|  \cdot \underbrace{\int_{-R_n}^{R_n} \frac{e^{(a+1) \cdot t}}{(e^t+1)^2} \, dt}_{\geq c>0} \end{align*}$$

Consequently, $|\sin(R_n)| \to 0$ is a necessary condition for the convergence of $I_2(R_n)$. This implies $|\cos(R_n)| \to 1$. Without loss of generality, we may assume $\cos(R_n) \to 1$ or $\cos(R_n) \to -1$ (otherwise we choose a suitable subsequence). In the first case we find by the dominated convergence theorem,

$$I_2(R_n) \to I_2 := \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{a \cdot t} + e^{(a+1) \cdot t}}{(e^t+1)^2} \, dt$$

Obviously, $I_2>0$, i.e. $I(R_n)$ does not converge to $0$. In the other case, i.e. $\cos(R_n) \to -1$, we have

$$I_2(R_n) \to I_2 := \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{a \cdot t} - e^{(a+1) \cdot t}}{(e^t+1)^2} \, dt$$

Actually, it depends on $a$ whether this integral equals $0$ or not. For example, if $a=1/2$, it's not difficult to see that $I_2=0$. But in general, $I_2 \neq 0$. This means that in both cases $I(R_n) \to 0$ does in general **not** hold.

---

Concerning your original problem: Choose a sequence $R_n \to \infty$ and $R_n \notin \{(2k+1) \cdot \pi; k \in \mathbb{Z}\}$. Set $r_n := \frac{1}{\sqrt{R_n}}$. We consider the contour integral

$$\int_{D_n} \frac{e^{a \cdot z}}{1+e^z} \, dz$$

where the parametrization of $D_n$ is given by $z(t) = R_n \cdot e^{\imath \, t}$, $t \in [0,\pi]$. We split up the integral as follows

$$\begin{align*} \int_{D_n} \frac{e^{a \cdot z}}{1+e^z} \, dz &= \underbrace{\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}-r_n} \frac{e^{a \cdot z(t)}}{1+e^{z(t)}} \cdot z'(t)\, dt}_{=: J_1} \\ &\quad + \underbrace{\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}-r_n}^{\frac{\pi}{2}+r_n} \frac{e^{a \cdot z(t)}}{1+e^{z(t)}} \cdot z'(t)\, dt}_{=: J_2}+\underbrace{\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}+r_n}^{\pi} \frac{e^{a \cdot z(t)}}{1+e^{z(t)}} \cdot z'(t)\, dt}_{=: J_3} \end{align*}$$

and estimate the terms separately. Some standard calculations and estimats yield

$$\begin{align*} |J_1| &\leq R_n \cdot \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}-r_n} \frac{e^{a \cdot R_n \cdot \cos(t)}}{e^{R_n \cdot \cos(t)}-1} \, dt \end{align*}$$

The mapping $t \mapsto \frac{e^{a \cdot R \cdot \cos(t)}}{e^{R \cdot \cos(t)}-1}$ is monotonely increasing on $[0,\pi/2-r_n]$, therefore

$$|J_1| \leq R_n \cdot \frac{\pi}{2} \cdot \frac{e^{a \cdot R_n \cdot \cos(\pi/2-r_n)}}{e^{R_n \cdot \cos(\pi/2-r_n)}-1} \to 0 \quad (n \to \infty)$$

(Note that $R_n \cdot \cos(\pi/2-r_n) \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$ and $a \in (0,1)$.) Similarly, we find

$$|J_3| \leq R_n \cdot \frac{\pi}{2} \cdot \frac{e^{a \cdot R_n \cdot \cos(\pi/2+r_n)}}{1-e^{R_n \cdot \cos(\pi/2+r_n)}} \to 0 \quad (n \to \infty)$$

The convergence of the term $|J_2|$ is rather obvious. This shows

$$\left| \int_{D_n} \frac{e^{a \cdot z}}{1+e^z} \, dz \right| \to 0$$

as $n \to \infty$. Therefore, the claim follows from the residue theorem.

Comment: I have added some additional information to provide context. I guess we have a case of things falling apart in the limit here, but thankfully it's not necessary. Thank you for explaining the divergence of the integral.

Comment: @DepeHb I have added some hints how to solve your original problem.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't taken complex analysis so I don't know the validity of this, but if 0

By some basic limit laws the limit of e^(az)/(1+e^z) as z goes to infinity = lim as (e^az)/(e^z) as z goes to infinity = 0.

How this applies to any integral definitions in complex analysis, I don't know. Also note that e^z/(1+e^z) = .5tanh(.5z) + .5.

Wish I could help more but I am coming at this problem with only real analysis knowledge.